# Append component in React

Tags: reactjs

Consider this structure of app:

```
<App>
  <SideBar/>
  <ProductsInterface/>
</App>
```

*ProductsInterface* renders an component called *ProductList*. I have another component called *Filter* and it's props depend on *ProductList*. It means i have to render it inside there.The problem is that i need it to be aligned on left, right under sidebar, not in *ProductsInterface* component. I tried to move it left with css but i think there are methods like **ReactDOM.render**(which says that div is not an valid element for appending) which i can append that Filter under a component or an html element with.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I recommend it, but you can use [ReactDOM.createPortal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render a component anywhere in the dom:

```
<App>
  <SideBar/>
  <div id="filters"></div>
  <ProductsInterface/>
</App>
```

Filters.js

```
...
render () {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal( <div>...</div>, document.getElementById('filters'))
}
```

The first argument for `createPortal` is the JSX to be rendered and the second arg is the DOM element to render it in. BUT, I would recommend you use CSS to position it underneath the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be using a state manager like [redux](https://redux.js.org/). So you'd be able to get any part of the state in any component without a need to nest them into each other. Or maybe [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) can help you to share some state between components.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to refactor your app's component structure, you can create a common ancestor for `<Filter />` and `<ProductList/>` that passes state to both components as props. So instead of having this:

```
<App>
    <SideBar/>
    <ProductsInterface>
        <ProductList>
            <Filter/>
        </ProductList>
    </ProductsInterface>
</App>
```

You would have something like this:

```
<App>
    <ProductInfo> //product-related state lives here
        <Sidebar/>
        <Filter/>
        <ProductsInterface>
            <ProductList/>
        </ProductsInterface>
    </ProductInfo>
</App>
```

This allows you to put the filter at the bottom of the sidebar, since the components are siblings.  `<Filter/>` could then receive functions like `filterProducts()` as props from `<ProductInfo/>` (its immediate parent). This would look like the following in `ProductInfo.js`'s render method:

`<Filter propName="this.filterProducts"></Filter>`

Then set up your `onClicks` in  `<Filter/>` to call the function from its props, which will update the state in `<ProductInfo/>` and by extension the contents of `<ProductList/>` (since it's receiving the `<ProductInfo/>` state as props).

This pattern is called [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and is fairly common in React applications. I would definitely recommend researching it further as you develop your strategy for organizing your component tree.